# Can ubuntu be installed on a USB 3.0, not talking about live usb, i want to install it on usb itself?

Tags: installation, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)

Can ubuntu be installed on a USB 3.0, not talking about live usb, i want to install it?

I was thinking about buying a 16/32 gb usb 3.0 pendrive and install ubuntu on it.

i am sure that ubuntu could be installed on a usb 2.0 stick, but not sure if you can really install ubuntu on usb 3.0. wanted to make sure before buying usb 3.0.
TIA
kalpav

Comment: What's the difference between installing Ubuntu on a USB-stick and installing a live cd on a USB-stick?

Comment: Can we please reopen this question? Or atleast supply links to other questions with confirmed answers? The below answer does not solve the question, because the user didn't fully understand the question. Startup Disk Creator can only be used on USB flash drives upto 4 GB. Anything larger, and the extra space will just be left empty.  I am wanting to do this same thing. Have a Live USB that is atleast 16 to 32 GB. Installing to the USB flash drive the way he suggests doesn't work for me either. Ubiquity crashes everytime after a certain percentage point. Please provide more links to information

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can from Startup Disk Creator app. If I were you, I might consider buying an external hard disk instead. Pen drivers larger than 8GB are slow, and relatively has a shorter lifetime, because they don't physically get larger even capacity does. That's just a theory... choice is yours.